# Form builder for FSE Theme

Tags: wordpress, forms, wordpress-gutenberg

I need to build a very small contact form with the following fields: name, email, telephone, select (with a list of choices) and the message.

Is there a free plugin that works with FSE Theme and allows the creation of the Form via blocks?

Thank you